# TypeError: <lambda>() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

```
ranges = (-0.4, -0.35, -0.3, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15 ,0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4)
number_observations =
df.groupby(pandas.cut(df['price_variation'], ranges)).count()

matplotlib.pyplot.bar(x = ranges, y = number_observations)
```

I am sorry, relatively new to StackOverflow as well as Python. I have a database of 20.000 price_variation. Thanks to the second line of code I grouped them by a range, but I am unable to do display the result in a graph. Does someone understand the error message? Or have another proposition for me to display the result?

Thanks a lot for the help!!

Comment: You x axis values should be ranges generated by pandas cut. You can try df.groupby(pandas.cut(df['price_variation'], ranges)).count().plot.bar()

Comment: Wonderful it works!! Thanks a lot Vaishali. One last question do you have any idea on how to display on the column 'Bin_spread' in the graph please?

Comment: not sure what you mean by displaying column bin_spread. The code above should display the bins as x ticks

Answer (score 2):

`y` is not a valid argumnt for `bar` plots. You need to specify the `height`. Since you have continuous bins with equal spacing you can specify the bin width and the edge alignment to make it so they appear as they should.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'price_variation': np.random.normal(0,0.12,10000)})

ranges = (-0.4, -0.35, -0.3, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15 ,0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4)
number_observations = df.groupby(pd.cut(df['price_variation'], ranges)).count()
```

#### Plot

```
# Get the bins and alignment correct
plt.bar(x=ranges[:-1], 
        height=number_observations.price_variation.values,
        width=np.diff(ranges)[0], 
        ec='k',
        align='edge')
plt.show()
```

[image]